# Can you Split $\rm CO_2$ using Microwave Heat?

Tags: energy-conservation, estimation, satellites, microwaves, chemical-compounds

I'm a layman, so maybe I didn't put the right searches in google to find the answer, but -

**If you microwave $\rm CO_2$ (Carbon Dioxide) to a sufficient temperature then can you split it to $\rm C$ and $\rm O_2$?**

I'm curious about the possibility of breaking down $\rm CO_2$ in atmospheres using satellites that broadcast Microwaved focused waves or perhaps MASERs for atmospheres such as Venus - a place already hot and under high pressure.

The only references i can find online deal with $\rm CO_2$ splitting with the use of catalysts or by using plasma reactors.

*(posted in Physics instead of Chemistry because, as far as i know, the effects of EM Photons are more in line with Physics instead of chemistry)*

Comment: Even if you could, the carbon would spontaneously combust at that temperature in the presence of oxygen, so you'd be right back where you started.

Comment: @IanF1: that would only happen if the dissociation products weren't separated and were cooled down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At sufficiently high temperature all chemical bonds eventually break. Above that temperature (which depends from chemical compound to chemical compound) chemistry ceases to exist.

For the dissociation of $\rm CO_2$ we can write the following equilibrium equation:

$$\rm CO_2(g) \iff C(s) + O_2(g)$$

And the following equilibrium constant:

$$K_\textrm{diss}=\frac{a_\mathrm C \times a_\mathrm{O_2}}{a_\mathrm{CO_2}}$$

Where the indexed $a$ are *chemical activities* (simply put: concentrations).

Because $\rm CO_2$ is a very stable compound, at STP (and fairly low temperatures) $K_\textrm{diss}$ is very, very small and the dissociation completely negligible.

Chemical stability (resistance to breakdown/dissociation) of a *specific chemical compound* is related to a concept called *Gibbs Free Energy of Formation*, denoted $\Delta G_f^T$. For stable compounds $\Delta G_f^T<0$ and the higher the stability, the more negative $\Delta G_f^T$ is.

The equilibrium constant $K_\textrm{diss}$ and $\Delta G_f$ are in turn related via Nernst:

$$\Delta G_f^T=-RT\ln K_\textrm{diss}^T$$

The corollary of this relation is that as temperature goes up, so does $K_\textrm{diss}^T$. If we reach a temperature where $K_\textrm{diss}^T\approx 1$, that would mean that about half of the $CO_2$ is dissociated into its constituent $C$ and $O_2$.

Whether or not this can be achieved with microwave heating becomes largely a technological problem. The power $P$ absorbed by an object subjected to microwave radiation can be described by:

$$P=\alpha P_\textrm{microwave}$$

Where $\alpha$ is an absorption coefficient.

Depending then on any heat losses and heat capacity the object will then reach a steady state temperature which may (or may not) be high enough to cause significant dissociation. *A priori* I see no problem in reaching such a temperature with microwave heating but all depends on the precise set up.

Comment: here one can find the absorption coefficient for CO2 http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=AD0019700 page 42  . Seems it needs ultraviolet to dissociate to  CO and O,  microwaves not good at that.